# XML validation - known and unknown attributes optional?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

please tell me whether it is possible and, if possible. How to declare in the xsd, that all attributes in my xml are optional. I cannot declare all attributes, because my xml has different number of attributes, both known and unknown.

```
        schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdFileInputStream));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if i understood this, you cannot modify each element in XSD but you would like to declare some global flag which would turn all elements into optional ?

Comment: yes, all attributes in each element.

Comment: but you need to modify the XSD, you cannot do this with validator instance.

Comment: Yes, I want to do. But I do not know how.

Comment: <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" allAttributesAreOptional="true" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: something like that. - allAttributesAreOptional="true"

Comment: I don't think there is such thing, but would be also interested to see if somebody knows about such option.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

```
<xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify each element in XSD, then it is as simple as this:

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

This is how you can declare atribute as optional:

```
<xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
```

And not sure if i got the final requirement right, you would like to do this auto-magically.
There is no global flag which would make this possible but you could create script like this:

- open XSD file in in Java
- read line by line
- if you detect `<xs:sequence>`, turn on modification algorithm bellow
- look for declaration of element or attribute  in a given line
- if there is element , append to it occurrence rules
- attributes are optional by default, so if they contain "required", change it to optional
- when you find `</xs:sequence>`, turn off modification algorithm
- repeat until no more lines

Note: do this manipulation on String which will replace content of the file once parsing is done.

Comment: I can not declare " minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" " in root element. It is not allowed.

Comment: that would require modification to parse only of  elements in </xs:sequence> tags.

Comment: What to do? The root element has attributes.

Comment: So always modify attributes. Don't touch elements unless they are within sequence. If the XSDs are black boxes which should not be modified by hand, you will have to write some parser like this. But honestly, i dont see why you wouldn't simply change all elements and attributes by hand,

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 allows you to say

```
<xs:schema defaultAttributes="defaultAttGroup"...

<xs:attributeGroup name="defaultAttGroup">
  <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

which is equivalent to adding an attribute wildcard to every complex type.