# How to validate xml with 'minOccurs' in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm using `javax.xml.validation.Validator` for validating xml against schema. I have a requirement where the input xml contains 'minOccurs' and 'maxOccurs' fields. If I validate this against schema, I'm getting `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 7; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'minOccurs' is not allowed to appear in element`. How to resolve this?

Validation:

```
URL url;
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
url = classLoader.getResource(schemaLocation);
String xsd = url.toURI().getPath();
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
File f = new File(xsd);
schema = factory.newSchema(f);
Validator valid = schema.newValidator();
StringReader xml = new StringReader(request);
valid.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
xml.close();
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="order">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<order>  
  <item>
    <name minoccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">apple</name>   
  </item>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to validate your XML againt the provided XSD will give you the following error:

> Attribute 'minoccurs' Cannot Appear In Element 'element'.

The XSD Indicators [specification](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp) tells that Occurrence indicators are :

> maxOccurs
>
> minOccurs

With an **Uppercase** 'O'

Change your XSD to :

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

And your XML to :

```
<order>  
  <item>
    <name>apple</name>   
  </item>
</order>
```

Comment: They probably also should not show up in the actual XML.

Comment: Chaged XSD, though the same is validated correctly in MSXML. Any way to validate in Java?

Comment: You need to remove **minoccurs** and **maxOccurs** from your XML file. If you let them into the  XML, then the validation will look for two elements named "minoccurs" and "maxOccurs" which are not defined into your XSD.

Comment: I was wondering why this works in MSXML. Is this because of SAXParser?

Comment: I do not know why, may be the SAX parser is more strict that the MS one you are using. For me the issue is not **related to Java nor MS**. If you use an agnostic xml validador like this [one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) you will figure that tour initial XML was not valid against your original XSD...

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MSXML with schema validation enabled? If it allows this through with schema validation enabled, then it's definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `minoccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"` in the xml element name.

What you need is :

```
<order>  
  <item>
    <name>apple</name>   
  </item>
</order>
```

With your current code it's looking for an attribute `minoccurs` and `maxOccurs` which you didn't define in your xsd file.

**Edit :**

If you want to use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` as attributes of your element `name` and keep
`<name minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">apple</name>` then you need to declare those attributes in your XSD like so.

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="minOccurs" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="maxOccurs" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: the same is validated correctly in MSXML. Any way to validate in Java?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSXML, like @Nirekin said it could be that it's not as strict.
If you want your original XML to work you need to declare those attributes in your XSD or see this post to allow unknown attributes [XML validation - known and unknown attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219189/xml-validation-known-and-unknown-attributes-optional).